# AWS Websocket on invoked lambda ignore message and send the last message received instead

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway

When I invoke a lambda that send data to client through the websocket API, it doesn't send the actual message/payload but the last received.

Example:

1. Lambda 1 invoke Lambda 2 with payload "test1" > Lambda 2 send nothing to client
2. Lambda 1 invoke Lambda 2 with second payload "test2" > Lambda send 2 send "test1" to client
3. Lambda 1 invoke Lambda 2 with third payload "test3" > Lambda send 2 send "test2" to client

[image]

My environnement:

- Nodejs 16
- lib websocket: AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection

There is 0 cache on Websocket API. There is no Error, just weird behavior.
The correct policies are set (invoke lambda, call dynamo, send message to websocket API)
I log the corect payload at lambda 2

Lambda 1 Code:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk") ;
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: "eu-west-1" });

const invokeLambda = async( functionName, payload) => {
  try {
    await lambda
      .invoke({
        FunctionName: `${functionName}`,
        InvocationType: "Event",
        Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error( err, `Error during the invokation of the lambda ${functionName}` );
  }
}
```

Lambda 2 Code:

```js
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
  endpoint: process.env.WEBSOCKET_DOMAIN_NAME,
});
import { InvokeResponseDto } from "../dto";

export const handler = async (
  event: InvokeRequestDto
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> => {
  const { userId, data } = event;

  // Retrieve all websocket 
  const items = await dynamo.scan(....)

  // Send message on websocket to all connection
  items?.forEach(async (item) => {
    try {
      const params : InvokeResponseDto = {
        ConnectionId: item.connectionId,
        Data: JSON.stringify(data),
      }
      await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, "ERROR at apigwManagementApi: ");
    }
  });
  console.info(`Sending the websocket message to ${items?.length} websockets`);

  return { statusCode: 200 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I
change **forEach** loop to a **for** loop.

from:

```
items?.forEach(async (item) => {
  await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise()
});
```

to:

```
for (const item of items) {
  await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise()
}
```

I can't explain it, but it works, message are sent instantly to websocket.